# Why Medit takes some GBs of RAM?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machine

Can you explain me in Linux, why a text editor with few files open no more than 200 lines long takes some GBs in memory?

MEDIT (a text editor) takes 1.2gb in virtual memory, 50.8mb in resident memory, 22.4mb in shared memory, and 84.6mb in disk write operations. Even MBs looks to me huge quantities for text files.

My hypothesis:

1. When you open an app in Linux, the mem stats takes into
   considerations all other intermidiate processes eg. `mem` to write data
   to disk, journal, logs, etc.

   - Then I propose, two stats must be referred, 1 for the program itself and one for the shared operations.
2. Mem stats are very
   relative of the memory consume and not actual `mem` stats - then where are actual `mem` stats?
3. I dont know.

[image: system memory process]

Comment: How much RAM does Medit eat without files open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you explain me in Linux, why a text editor with few files open no more than 200 lines long takes some GBs in memory?
>
> MEDIT (a text editor) takes 1.2gb in virtual memory, 50.8mb in resident memory, 22.4mb in shared memory, and 84.6mb in disk write operations. Even MBs looks to me huge quantities for text files.

That sounds like it *doesn't* take "some GBs" in memory. It only occupies 51 MB total – "resident" is the stat you should be looking at.

"Virtual memory" is not RAM usage. (Don't confuse it with the Windows terminology, where the same term means a very different thing – swap/pagefile usage.) The statistic on Linux represents *virtual address space* usage, and the address space can be mapped to various things that aren't necessarily in RAM:

- all the libraries used by the program are memory-mapped, meaning that they're represented by an address range even though they're not loaded into RAM *yet*; they will be loaded on-demand, page-by-page, whenever the program attempts to access that memory area.
- working files can also be memory-mapped instead of using traditional read/write/seek calls; this is especially common for database files but can be used for any file type. Again, even if the entire file is mapped into virtual memory at once, it is still only loaded into RAM on-demand.
- the actual "resident" RAM is allocated as anonymous mappings in large chunks ("arenas"), which can be much larger than the amount currently being used. For example, every thread (and a GUI app will have threads) might get its own 128 MB arena upfront even if it hasn't requested any memory allocation yet.

  (Previously, it was not uncommon to see Golang or Haskell programs preemptively mapping a *terabyte* of address space for all of their upcoming memory allocations.)
- some software (such as JavaScript runtimes in particular) will map huge amounts of address space as a "guard" (see e.g. Webkit's Gigacage); the mapping remains completely empty and does not consume any RAM.

Virtual address space is independent from physical RAM and is separate for each process, so there's nothing wrong even with a program having more memory mappings than you have RAM.

> Even MBs looks to me huge quantities for text files.

It's not the text file, it's the program itself and the libraries it uses. For example, just the 'Pango' font-rendering library is half a megabyte (and the actual international fonts can easily be multiple megabytes on top of that); the 'GTK' widget toolkit is 8 MB because libgtk-3.so has all of the assets built into it (i.e. SVGs and PNGs of checkboxes, sliders, and such); and so on.

(Technically programs could do without all of that support code, but that inevitably leads to homegrown "lightweight" toolkits that don't support anything but Latin characters, don't know what "HiDPI" is, etc.)

Use `pmap -x <pid>` (there are probably GUI tools as well) to see the virtual memory allocation of a process, which will show "resident" statistics individually for each item.

Answer (score 3):

Virtual memory on Linux is very different from virtual memory on Windows. There is overcommitting, and you can see that basically *all* processes make liberal use of that fact. They actually did request all that memory, but they are not using it, which is evident from the other memory values.

Medit is not that simple an editor either: It appears to be GTK-based, has plugin interfaces, a file system browser and a terminal built-in.

Unless you have a specific problem with memory, the “solution” is simple: Ignore the virtual memory size column.

Only “simple” applications (no complex memory allocations) will have a virtual size close to the actual resident memory size. Bigger applications often request memory in larger blocks to keep the “real” amount of allocations low-ish, allowing better system performance overall and less memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that all your programs are marked as using heaps of virtual memory,
in amounts that approach or exceed one gigabyte.

Virtual memory stands for the virtual size of a process, which is the
sum of memory it is actually using.
This includes memory it has mapped into itself (for instance the
video card’s RAM for the X server), files on disk that have been mapped
into it (most notably shared libraries) and memory shared with
other processes.

Virtual memory in other words represents how much memory the program
is able to access, which includes both code and data.

I believe that the largest part of the marked 1.2 GB used by MEDIT
is composed of shared libraries that it uses. Libraries such as `libc`
are huge. However, as they are shared, although they are counted in
the virtual memory of every process that uses them, in real physical
memory only one copy actually exist in reality.

In short, this virtual memory size is really virtual and not indicative
of much.